# jQuery strange behaviour whith hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, hover, addclass

I have a strange issue with jQuery's hover, addClass

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selectable li').hover(
            function(){
                $(this).addClass('selecting', 600);
            },
            function(){
                $(this).removeClass('selecting', 800);
            }
    );

});
```

The strange is now that the selected element lights up twice. How can this be? What do I do to prevent two light ups?

Best Regards,
B. Kaiser

Comment: you could probably get the results you need without javascript and just pure css

Comment: What do you intend with the parameters 600 and 800?

Comment: What's the 600 and 800 for? .addClass() has no time parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an alternative such as this :

```
$('#selectable li').on('mouseenter',function(){
  $(this).addClass('selecting');
}).on('mouseleave',function(){
  $(this).removeClass('selecting');
});
```

<sub>You'll need a current version of jQuery.  [ver 1.7+](http://jquery.com)</sub>

Not too sure that you are trying to accomplish with the numeric parameters in your `addClass/removeClass` calls.  The [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) defines those functions as follows :

> http://api.jquery.com/addClass/
>
> **.addClass( className )**
>   classNameOne or more class names to be added to
>   the class attribute of each matched element.
>
> **.addClass( function(index, currentClass) )**
>   function(index, currentClass)A function returning one or more space-separated class
>   names to be added to the existing class name(s). Receives the index
>   position of the element in the set and the existing class name(s) as
>   arguments. Within the function, this refers to the current element in
>   the set.

The [`removeClass()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) works pretty much the same way too.

Comment: What's the 600 and 800 for? .addClass() has no time parameter.

Comment: Hover should be perfectly fine here. No need for additional event binding. BTW: You have a typo in the word `function`.